# Loop with runas command prompt (cmd)

Tags: loops, input, passwords, command, runas

How can we use loop command as example below:

```
runas /user:nsrv\john "a.bat"
```

If we input wrong password, it will ask input again again and again until we input right password.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it hahaha

```
:Loop
@echo Type password:
runas /user:john "a.bat"
if errorlevel equ 1 goto :Loop
```